# MySQL 5 (32bits) on Windows 2008 server

Tags: mysql, windows-server-2008

As above, anyone tried that before on Windows 2008 server? If yes, how is everything go? Stable enough for production use?

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully (as in no problems with the default install and operate) done the following several times:

Transferred a major application built on LAMP (ubuntu and others) to WAMP (2008 server).

Operated both SQL Server and MySQL 5 from the same 2008 server simultaneously.

Been running MySQL 5 and SQL Server simultaneously on my dev laptop for over a year (both as nonstop services).

Upgraded all cases from 5.0 to 5.1.

Tuned queries and database config on laptop, and implemented the results on the server with corresponding benefits.

I'd be very surprised if you ever see a hiccup that's attributable to the operating system.